# what is the diffrence between topics and services

Tags: ros, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
i am pretty new to ROS and i want to know that if we see practically then both topic and service are performing the same task then how we can differentiate between the two in real life  robot task

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278426/what-is-the-diffrence-between-topics-and-services/) by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think #q11834 is just about the authoritative Q&A on this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1